Проблема, с пониманием приоритета операций, при разыменовывании
Вопрос довольно глупый, но я никак не могу с ним разобраться, а chatGPT каждый раз противоречит сам себе, при ответе. Почему, при:
int array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int *p = array;
int x = (*p++)++;

Я получаю array[4] = {2,2,3,4} Ведь по логике унарных операторов, все должно читаться справа - налево. Вроде, у разыменования приоритет выше, но почему при записи int x = (*p++) происходит сначала сдвиг, а потом разыменование?

происходит сначала сдвиг, а потом разыменование? - с чего вы это взяли???

@MBo потому-что, в результате int x = (*p++), мне возвращает 2.

@zzzackxv 2 будет возвращено в любом случае, разве нет?

@MBo, адреса, ведь разные, сами проверьте

https://i.sstatic.net/fz3JjWi6.png

@Qwertiy 9 и 10 строки,видимо, придают надёжности

@MBo, это же присваивание указателя p, а потом начало вычислений с ним (впрочем, адрес заинлайнился снова)?

Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

А еще в вопросе стоит тег С, а на картинке показан код С++, причем невалидный.


Ведь по логике унарных операторов, все должно читаться справа - налево

Но в выражении ведь скобки стоят.

происходит сначала сдвиг, а потом разыменование?

Неправда. В таком случае получилось бы {1,3,3,4}.

Я получаю array[4] = {2,2,3,4}

(*p++)++
  ^------------ взяли указатель p
   ^^---------- увеличили на 1
  ^^^---------- но продолжаем работать со старым значением
 ^------------- разыменовали - получилась 1 в нулевом элементе
^----^--------- скобки только для приоритета операций
      ^^------- увеличили на 1 (в массиве)
^^^^^^^^------- и вернули старое значение

Вот можно посмотреть ассемблерный код: https://godbolt.org/z/vMhaav1qe


Я только что перепроверил, мне кажется дело в компиляторе (MSVC), видимо это звонок о переходе на GCC, потому-что, когда я решался это проверить, такой результат и ожидал (*p++)++, сдвиг в скобках, разыменование, увеличение на 1. Я прикреплю, скриншот к посту вопроса

@zzzackxv, (*++p)++ напиши тогда.


происходит сначала сдвиг, а потом разыменование?

Правда. В обоих выражениях (*p++)++; и (*p++) сначала производится инкремент p++, и только затем разыменование, так как приоритет постфиксного инкремента выше. Важно, что новое значение указателя p в этих выражениях не используется, ведь постфиксный инкремент возвращает исходное значение операнда, поэтому изменяется только первый элемент массива.
